# API authentication with mobile app (by SMS)

Tags: api, security, mobile, architecture

We are currently tasked with implementing a (preferably simple) authentication system for a mobile application communication with a RESTful API. The backend has user-specific data, identified by the user's phone number. I am trying to understand more about security in general, the different methods there are and why they work the way they work.

I thought of a simple authentication system:

- The client sends a verification request to the api which includes their phone number and a generated guid.
- The server sends an SMS message to the phone number with a verification code.
- The client verifies their device by sending their unique guid, phone number and verification code.
- The server responds with some kind of access token which the client can use for further requests.

I have the following questions:

Are there any major flaws in this approach?
Assuming we use HTTPS, is it secure enough to send the data otherwise unencrypted?
Can access tokens be stored on mobile devices safely so that only our app can read them?
Anything else we haven't thought of?

We already figured that when the mobile phone is stolen or otherwise compromised, the data is no longer secure, but that is a risk that is hard to overcome. Access tokens could be valid temporarily to minimize this risk.

I am assuming this approach is way to simple and there is a huge flaw somewhere :) Can you enlighten me?

Comment: You might be interested in reading about oauth2.0 - http://oauth.net/2/ It's the current trend in authentication. Basically the client opens opens a web page, maintained by the service provider, for the user to log in his/hers account, the client is redirected to a page where an access codes is received (which is available for short time) and then this code is exchanged for a pair of access token and refresh token. The access token is used to access the user's account and the refresh token - to refresh the access token.

Comment: I have read about oauth, but I do not think it is suitable for us. We do not allow logins through third-party authentication systems, so it seems like overkill. Users do not have a username and password, we only need to verify that they have access to the entered phone number (hence the verification sms). The data they can access is also tied to the phone number.

Comment: My point was that you described an authentication system similar to oauth2.0. Maybe the oauth's pros and cons (access tokens, security, etc.) would be valid for your system

Comment: Your system sounds a lot like googles 2 factor authentication. The main difference being that you haven't said how you know the phone is the right one for the person. In Googles set up, the user has to use their user/pass to put in a phone, and then it is associated. The main weakness I would highlight, is the one you bring up yourself, which is that the tokens are valid for some amount of time, something that you can control. So you might want to have some sort of revocation API to help with the lost phone scenario.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a flaw. The system is susceptible to a brute-force attack.

Suppose I am an attacker. I will generate a guid for myself and send it along with some arbitrary phone number.

Next, I will just bruteforce my way through the possible SMS codes - if it's 6 digits, there's  only 10^6 combinations. The bruteforce will be a matter of seconds - and then I will gain acess to the data of the person having this phone.

Also, as was pointed out in the comment by Filou, one can force you to send you arbitrary number of SMS, effectively making you sustain a financial loss at no cost.

There's also no valid defense from this attack:

1. If there is limited amount (N) of attempts for a given UID, I will
   re-generate the guid every N attempts.
2. If there's a limit of requests per phone per amount of time, I can execute a DoS/DDoS attack by flooding every possible number with fake requests - hence, noone will be able to perform any requests.

A login/password or certificate authenication is **mandatory** before an SMS. Also:

1. Never use things like GUID in cryptography/security protocols. GUIDs are deterministic (i.e., knowing one value, you can predict future ones). Use crypto-libraries built-in functions for generating random streams
2. Never try to design security protocols yourself. Never. There's an awful lot of caveats even SSL 1.0 creators fell to - and they were sharp guys, mind you. Better copy common and proven schemes (Google's auth is a great example).

Comment: 1. yes, but even in your example, given a small N,  N / 10^6 is close to zero, although admittedly not zero. so the question would be if the verification code is entered manually, ie how complex can it be? 2. you did not mention the financial loss of sending an uncontrolled number of sms, so you might need a counter measure. If user, ie GUID/phone, registration is secure I think it would work, other wise (or even for more safety) use a login/password beforehand as suggested. pretty much also what google does in its 2-step verification approach.

Comment: There's no "N". 10^6 is the number of possible SMS codes. And if the SMS code is lengthy (at least 10 symbols - specials+alphanumeric - is required to make it close to 2^64 combinations, which is "better than average, but still bad"), password might do as good instead of SMS. Keep in mind that Google *has* password authentication before the SMS/OTP step.

Comment: Meh didnt see your full reply.. 10^6 is the number of possible SMS codes, agreed. N is the limited number of attempts for a given UID and verification code before some measure is taken. So the probability of guessing correct or using brute force for that matter is around N / 10^6, or am I wrong? Being lenient towards typos and allowing M retries results in a success probability of about 1 - ((10^6-N)/10^6)^M , which is still relatively small unless you're being overly lenient. If it's an attack over a long time, that might circumvent any such countermeasures, but that's a different story.. ?

Comment: Ahh, I see now. I didn't remember I was using N in my answer myself :) However, author does not specify that the GUID is tied to the number. Rather, it is some random generated GUID which is different every time (like in challenge/response). At least this is how OP describes his scheme. Hence, if the server blocks me, I'll just generate new GUID and go ahead with bruteforcing (as I've described in my answer)

Comment: It is a generated Guid. More specifically, it will be generated once when you first start the mobile app, and will stay the same after that. As far as I know, there is no real way to uniquely identify a specific phone. When you reiunstall the app the Guid will be different.

Comment: The problem we have is that the only reliable identifier in the data is the phone number. So the only way for us to identify whether or not a user can access the data, is to prove he has possession of that phone number. We will probably set a limit for the amount of verification attempts per phone number before it gets blocked, regardless of what device id is used. Like you said, this does mean that someone with bad intentions can block a load of phone numbers by hammering the api with attempts, but we see no real way around this. Oauth or something similar will not solve this problem.

Comment: Well, if you're willing to take that risk - that's up to you. Just keep in mind your service can still be abused by sending SMS to a lot of random numbers; that number of attempts should be very low - 3 per day? (considering the probability to guess the code); and that SMS is still not very secure (what if someone takes a friend's phone for a few minutes? Will he be able to do much damage?). An alternative is a real two-factor auth. Oauth is just a "pret-a-porter" technology to facilitate the security.

Answer (score 0):

The approach you mentioned will works fine. Client will initiate a request with the phone number and a random id, server returns a verification token to the device. The token is one time use only with a set expiry. Then client will send the phone number, the random token used before and the validation token, which the server verifies. If valid, server sends a session token (or auth token) or similar which can be used for authentication. The session token can have a time out set from the server.
You did not mention if it's a web app or not. If it's a web app, you can set a https only session cookie from the server. Otherwise, you can store it locally in the app's local store. In usual case, apps cannot read private data belonging to other apps.
All communications must take place using HTTPS. Otherwise the whole scheme can get compromised via sniffing for traffic, because in the end you are using the auth token.